# How to over ride Netbeans wizard toolbar save button function?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have an application developed in Netbeans 7.0 where there is a save button on the toolbar of the application ( which I think is provided by Netbeans) and a 2nd custom save button.

While saving using the custom save button I have to check whether all the fields are filled. if not it throws an error.
But this validation will not work if the user clicks the save button on the top (toolbar).

How can I override the save button in the toolbar of Netbeans wizard module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question can be found here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/bye_savecookie_hello_org_netbeans